# How to find noise sources from noise figure data?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, circuit-design, noise

An amplifier datasheet provides noise measurements that show it has a noise figure of 3dB for R_s = 100Ω and R_s = 10kΩ (same noise figure for both values of R_s) at T=300K and f=10kHz.[image: amplifier noise model]

I need to determine e_n and i_n at 10kHz from the noise figure data.

For e_n I think I need to use the equation e_n=sqrt(4kTR), but that doesn't take into account the frequencies given?
I am confused on what means by "a noise figure of 3dB" at those values and that there is the "same noise figure for both values of R_s".

Answer (score 1):

I think that the frequency is not needed to solve this task. It might indicate that we are dealing with noise above the 1/f flicker noise regime. Accordingly, the white noise (thermal noise), can be described according to the well-known Johnson-Nyquist equation.

So what do we know?

A noise figure of \$\mathrm{NF} = 3~\mathrm{dB}\$ corresponds to a noise factor of \$F = 10^{\frac{\mathrm{NF}}{10~\mathrm{dB}}} = 2\$.

The noise factor is defined as \$F = \frac{\text{noise power (density) of real amplifier}}{\text{noise power (density) of ideal amplifier}}\$.

So we ware able to state the equation \$F = \frac{e_{\mathrm{NS}}^2 + e_{\mathrm{n}}^2 + (R_{\mathrm{S}} i_{\mathrm{n}})^2}{e_{\mathrm{NS}}^2}\$.

Written slightly different: \$e_{\mathrm{NS}}^2 (F-1) = e_{\mathrm{n}}^2 + (R_{\mathrm{S}} i_{\mathrm{n}})^2\$.

Since we are dealing with thermal noise it holds that \$e_{\mathrm{NS}}^2 = 4 k T R_{\mathrm{S}}\$. With \$F = F_1 = F_2 = 2\$ for \$R_{\mathrm{S1}} = 100~\Omega\$ and \$R_{\mathrm{S2}} = 10~\mathrm{k}\Omega\$ we get two equations with the two unknowns \$e_{\mathrm{n}}\$ and \$i_{\mathrm{n}}\$:

\$
I) ~ 4 k T R_{\mathrm{S1}} = e_{\mathrm{n}}^2 + (R_{\mathrm{S1}} i_{\mathrm{n}})^2
\$

\$
II) ~ 4 k T R_{\mathrm{S2}} = e_{\mathrm{n}}^2 + (R_{\mathrm{S2}} i_{\mathrm{n}})^2
\$

Solving this system of equations (for example \$I - II\$) leads to:

\$
i_{\mathrm{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{4 k T (R_{\mathrm{S1}} - R_{\mathrm{S2}})}{R_{\mathrm{S1}}^2 - R_{\mathrm{S2}}^2}} = 1.3~\mathrm{pA}/\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}}
\$

and

\$
e_{\mathrm{n}} = \sqrt{4 k T R_{\mathrm{S1}} - (R_{\mathrm{S1}} i_{\mathrm{n}})^2} = \sqrt{4 k T R_{\mathrm{S2}} - (R_{\mathrm{S2}} i_{\mathrm{n}})^2} = 1.3~\mathrm{nV}/\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}}.
\$

Comment: This is a great answer!